# Detect and Set Column values between rows

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I have a table relating to products:

```
PRD_SLD table
ID   DATE   SALE_IND 
3    2012   0        
3    2013   0
3    2014   1
3    2014   1
3    2015   1
3    2016   0 
3    2017   1
```

I would like my final results to look like this:

```
PRD_SLD table
ID   DATE   SALE_IND   STRT   END
3    2012   0        2012    2014
3    2013   0        2012    2014
3    2014   1        2014    2016
3    2014   1        2014    2016
3    2015   1        2014    2016
3    2016   0        2016    2017
3    2017   1        2017    2017
```

I currently have a working CTE for retrieving the rows in which the values change. this CTE returns this:

```
PRD_SLD table
ID   DATE   SALE_IND 
3    2012   0        
3    2014   1
3    2016   0 
3    2017   1
```

So it returns the first instance of the value in the table, and returns every time the SALE_IND changes.

Is there a way to create a start and end date based off of the date column? I am still very new to this and was enrolled in an advanced course. I'm sure there is a better way to complete this but is there a way to do it with the CTE results i have created? I know there is a between function but i don't know how to implement it into this query

Answer (score 0):

One method is to define groups of adjacent records.  You don't have a solid ordering of the rows, but you do have just enough information for this to work -- assuming the indicator is constant in each year.

```
select t.*,
       min(year) over (partition by id, sale_ind, seqnum - seqnum_s) as min_year,
       max(year) over (partition by id, sale_ind, seqnum - seqnum_s) as max_year
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum,
             dense_rank() over (partition by id, sale_ind order by date) as seqnum_s
      from t
     ) t;
```